# Absolute path to file on input[type=file]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is is possible to get the ABSOLUTE path to a file using JavaScript or jQuery? These are my trials so far but the closest I can get is just the filename.

```
    var filepath = $('input[type=file]').val();
    var test = this.files;
    var test2 = test[0];
    var test3 = test2.fileName;
    var test4 = test2.filePath;
    var test5 = test2.Name;
    var h = imageInput.value;
    var b = document.getElementById("AcademicPhotoId");
    var l = b.value;
    var binary = b.getAsBinary();
    $('.image-display img').attr('src', filepath);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that would be a security violation.  (It could tell you the user's name, etc.  i.e.  `c:\Users\Kirk\Desktop\uploadedfile.txt`)

Out of curiosity, why do you desire this information?

Comment: I was trying to assign the absolute path to the img.src, see line
 $('.image-display img').attr('src', filepath);

Comment: @Homero, ah, yes, I understand what you want.  But what you want would make no sense unless the webpage was being served on the same machine as the user browsing the page.

Answer (score 2):

According to the specifications of HTML5, a file upload control should not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected, if you manipulate its value string with JavaScript. Instead, the string that is returned by the script, which handles the file information is `c:\fakepath`