# retrive selected url path from <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used normal file type I just want to know how can I retrieve selected file path I tried to do .val() function but in these case I am able to file out only file name not a whole location of file where it's store in my local machine can anyone please help me out regarding these....

thanks

Comment: val() retrieves the whole path not just the filename

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866309/absolute-path-to-file-on-inputtype-file

Comment: $('#upload').live('change', function(){alert("Pranali"+this.value) });I did these but I just got test.jpg not whole location where it's stored

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery will help

Comment: Why do you need the local path? What are you trying to do? Perhaps there are better alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because : It's a security feature in all browsers.

The full path on the client is not available to you. The browser acts as an intermediary, allowing the user to select a file, and sending the contents to the server, but never allowing the page to know any more than it absolutely must.

Comment: so is their any option because I want location of that file and I want to open in new popup box is their any way to do these

Comment: "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server"? What browser allows you to change that directive?

Comment: I don't want any server side changes I just want to pic my local file

Comment: Oj never mind, found that IE8 allows it from the linked question.

Comment: @ Fabrício Matté what exactly you mean to say Include local directory is it specific folder

Comment: @user2123421 I just quoted a part of the answer. Never mind it. It is well explained in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3489167/1331430) linked in your question's comments.